# QSpinBox not getting the int value from data

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt, qspinbox

So I have figured out how to dynamically generate controls how I wanted in QDialog for question i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688654/how-do-i-dynamically-add-controls-to-modles-qdialog-based-on-data-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment30983214_20688654) but now I am not able to set the value on QSpinBox from the dictionary
below

```
books = {
        'Contact':['Carl Sagan', 2],
        'End of Faith':['Sam Harris', 7],
        'on Mars':['Patrick Moore', 1],

        }


def buildUi(self):
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setSpacing(10)
    for index, (key, values) in enumerate(self._data.iteritems()):
        getLbl = QtGui.QLabel("Get", self)
        label = QtGui.QLabel(key, self)
        chkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self._data[key][0], self)
        chkBox.setToolTip("Click here to get the book")
        version = QtGui.QSpinBox(self._data[key][-1], self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(getLbl, index, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(label, index, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(chkBox, index, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(version, index, 3)
    self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.okBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
    self.layout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
    self.horLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horLayout.addStretch(1)
    self.horLayout.addWidget(self.okBtn)
    self.layout.addLayout(self.horLayout)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Development/custom/MessageBox.py", line 58, in _launchMessageBox
    dlg = MessageBox(self._data)
  File "~/Development/custom/MessageBox.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.buildUi()
  File "~/Development/custom/MessageBox.py", line 21, in buildUi
    version = QtGui.QSpinBox(self._data[key][-1], self)
TypeError: QSpinBox(QWidget parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
[Finished in 4.5s]
```

Also how do I set the limit in QSPinBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`QSpinBox.__init__` documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qspinbox.html#QSpinBox), it does take only `parent` parameter.

Replace following line:

```
version = QtGui.QSpinBox(self._data[key][-1], self)
```

with:

```
version = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)
```

---

If you want the initial value to be set, use [`setValue`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qspinbox.html#setValue):

```
version.setValue(self._data[key][-1])
```

Comment: and how do i set limit in QSpinBox?

Comment: @san, You can use `setRange` method or `setMinumum`/`setMaximum` methods.